# Allow negative primary keys in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

Is there any way to allow primary keys to be negative integers in Sails?
I ran accross the following error when testing some older software;

```
  {
    "code":"E_INVALID_VALUES_TO_SET",
    "details":"Could not use specified `org`. Expecting an id representing the associated record, or `null` to indicate there will be no associated record.  But the specified value is not a valid `org`.  Cannot use a negative number (-1) as a primary key value.",
    "message":"The server could not fulfill this request (`PATCH /user/1402`) due to a problem with the parameters that were sent.  See the `details` for more info.  **The following additional tip will not be shown in production**:  Tip: Check your client-side code to make sure that the request data it sends matches the expectations of the corresponding attribues in your model.  Also check that your client-side code sends data for every required attribute."}
```

I've checked the Sails documentation and can't find any place which mentions that negative primary keys are not allowed.

I've also checked the schema definitions for both tables, and neither speciefies the relevant field as unsigned.

Is there any workaround other than changing the relevant row to some different id and updating every other row which references it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround. Maybe you can change your primary key to a string.
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings